# Pass list of strings to webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, list, parameters

I have this code:

```
List<string> emailsToFollow = new List<string>();
ASMXWebServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient MyASMXWebServiceClient = new ASMXWebServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient();
//Add values to List here
//Call the webservice
ASMXWebServiceReference.SendResponse mySendResponse = await MyASMXWebServiceClient.SendAsync("g@gg.gg", emailsToFollow);
```

And in the webservice this is the title of my function:

```
public bool Send(string myEmail, string[] emaislToFollow)
```

The problem is that I got this error:

> Error Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'App9.ASMXWebServiceReference.ArrayOfString'

Why?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer and updating my post. Well, it seems that you have to make a bit of conversion here

```
ASMXWebServiceReference.ArrayOfString myArray = new ASMXWebServiceReference.ArrayOfString();
myArray.AddRange(emailsToFollow);
```

It seems that out of th service you have to use ArrayOfString class and convert your collection to this very spesific type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but that I got this error: Error 8 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'App9.ASMXWebServiceReference.ArrayOfString'

Answer (score 1):

change the signature of Send:

```
public bool Send(string myEmail, List<string> emaislToFollow)
```